How does ngen.exe calculate the "NGen GUID sign"?
I recently had an issue where one of my .NET Native Image assemblies was corrupt; forcing regeneration via ngen.exe update /force resolved the issue.
In trying to debug what went wrong, I compared the native image assembly folders before and after the re-ngen. The main difference was a single DLL, System.Management.Automation.ni.dll, with both a different location and content.
The different location of the ngen'ed DLL in .NET Framework 4 is due to a different NGen GUID sign as reported by running ngen.exe display System.Management.Automation /verbose.
I'm trying to understand more about how this NGen GUID sign is computed or looked up. In previous .NET versions, the location was determined by the Source MVID (also reported by the ngen command), which is located in the metadata of the source DLL. But the NGen GUID sign is not present in the source DLL. Knowing where it comes from would be helpful in trying to debug what caused the issue I encountered.
